# Open shift Auto scaling

Tags: openshift, autoscaling

I have few doubts regarding openshift auto scaling. Currently my application (java based web app) is on a  free open shift domain as auto scale, only one gear is free . How does auto scaling works for my application, do I have to make any server changes?

I have to deploy the same code on another gear also?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading through this FAQ on the OpenShift help center and see if it answers your questions: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202187174-How-does-scaling-work-in-OpenShift-

From the article: 
OpenShift supports the manual scaling as well as auto-scaling applications.

To create an scalable application, just create an application with the -s parameter:

> rhc app create {appName} {type} -s
>   Please note that this will create an app that uses 1 gear with the following cartridges:
>   1) the application framework/code
>   2) the load balancer (haproxy)

The application is set to automatically scale up or down depending on the load it receives.  These thresholds are:
1) scale up if the number of concurrent requests exceed 90% of max concurrent requests over 1 period.
2) scale down if the number of concurrent requests fall below 49.9% of max concurrent requests over 3 consecutive periods.
3) not configurable at this time
where max concurrent requests is 10 requests, and a period is 20s.

To switch between manual and auto-scaling, run:
Enable auto scaling (default):

> ssh $UUID@$APP-$DOMAIN.rhcloud.com rhcsh "haproxy_ctld_daemon start"
>   Disable auto scaling:
>   ssh $UUID@$APP-$DOMAIN.rhcloud.com rhcsh "haproxy_ctld_daemon stop"

To manually scale up or down, run:
Scale up:

> ssh $UUID@$APP-$DOMAIN.rhcloud.com rhcsh "haproxy_ctld -u"
>   Scale down:
>   ssh $UUID@$APP-$DOMAIN.rhcloud.com rhcsh "haproxy_ctld -d"

When embedding a database to a scalable application with the command:

> rhc cartridge add -a {scaleable_app} -c {database}
>   it will use up an additional gear as this database is 'externally addressable' and lives on its own gear.  That means all gears in the scaled application will be able to reach this database (as well as other applications/gears).

For more details, please review our User Guide:  http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Creating_Applications-Creating_Applications.html